# program understanding

Tags: csh

So i have an mkformal directory with three files which  i want to read

1)    formality_compile_vs_no_scan_netlist

2)  formality_rtl_vs_compile

3)  formality_compile_vs_final_netlist

Could you please explain what the following code is doing . I mean what is the foreach line and the if statement all doing .

```
foreach _file (logs/verify.log reports/match.rtl_vs_final_netlist.matched_unread.rpt)
    if (-f ${ms_mkformaldir}/$_file) then
        echo "          ...found '${ms_mkformaldir}/$_file'"|& tee -a ${ms_mksynth_sumrpt}
        setenv ms_inpfiles "$ms_inpfiles ${ms_mkformaldir}/$_file"
    endif
end
```

Comment: Huh? It has nothing to do with `awk`. It is looking for each of the named files in a directory called `ms_mkformaldir` and if it finds any, it appends their names to the variable `ms_inpfiles`.

Comment: It also has _nothing_ to do with `tcl`. Looks like `csh` (or a derivative) to me…